# ArrayList null when inistatiated in mockito's doAnswer()

Tags: java, arraylist, null, mockito

I'm using mockito and create a mock like this:

```
...
doAnswer(Helper.create()) //
.when(this.mock).someMethod(any(SomeClass.class));
...
```

The Helper creates an Answer, that answers an Instance which contains an empty list:

```
return new Answer<ReturnClass>() {
    @Override
    public ReturnClass answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        ReturnClass ret = new ReturnClass();
        ret.setList(new ArrayList()); // this is null at runtime
        // Solved by: ret.setList(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("item")));
        return ret;
    }
};
```

When running that test, the instance of ReturnClass is answered but it's list is null (leading to a NullPointerException when trying to iterate over it).

Adding an item to that list solves it.

Is there anything I can do to make empty lists possible?

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] demonstrating your case?

Comment: do you need to mutate a list after? if no, maybe returning `Collections.emptyList()` will help...

Comment: @Sasha Salauyou: will try tthis, thx!